# Public wifi router conflicts with company VPN IP address

Tags: routing, vpn, subnet

I'm a digital nomad and I like to work in cafes and co-working spaces. The problem is that sometimes the network router IP address conflicts with my company's VPN-client IP address.
Any and all requests to my company's internal network are routed to 172.*, and some are then routed to 10.* (an internal region)

While working at Panera, after I connected to the wifi, I was unable to access any 10.* websites on my company's internal VPN, because the Panera wifi created the following rule in my Mac's routing tables:

`10                 link#14            UCS                   en0      !`

After deleting that rule, and adding my own routing table rule, I was able to connect to the internal website:

```
% sudo route delete -net 10.0.0.0/8 -interface en0  
delete net 10.0.0.0: gateway en0
% sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0/8 -interface utun4 
add net 10.0.0.0: gateway utun4
```

And this worked fine at Panera. I was able to connect to the 10.* internal websites.

However, I moved to a different co-working space, and I have a different problem. It looks like the router itself is taking up the same IP address that my VPN tunnel uses, and when I start up the VPN software, I lose all internet.

[image: router IP address]

That Router IP address happens to be the exact same IP address that all my VPN traffic is supposed to be routing through. For example, when I run "nslookup" on any of my company's internal websites, here's the result

```
% nslookup example.internal.com
Server:     172.16.0.1
Address:    172.16.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.internal.com
Address: 10.102.120.40
```

So my question is what can I do on my local computer, whether through routing table rules or other VPN configuration, so that I can still connect to this router, and also the company's VPN?

For reference, the VPN client i'm using is called BIG-IP Edge Client and it's on a Mac M1. Would it be possible for me to carry around my own portable router that my laptop sees as a 192 address, and then connect that router to the public wifi so that it doesn't conflict?

Comment: Sorry, networks not under your control and host configurations are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. You should talk to you company's IT support or need to sort out the routes yourself.

Answer (score 1):

That's the unfortunate, and unavoidable, problem of using other people's networks. The former (10/8) issue should be addressed by your VPN client software -- install a /32 route to the router, and VPN gateway, and then two /1 routes to override any default gateway. The VPN server should also be telling the client about specific protected networks. (aka. split-tunnel)

The second scenario is harder to address. Without VRFs / "namespaces", it's hard to isolate things with the same address. VPN client software can deal with an inside and outside address being the same - it knows what interface is which. The issue is the rest of the OS.